# Jquery how to get top leftcorner of page?

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I would like to mask a asp page by a div, this one have to completly cover the page.

I can get the size of page and resize the div with this values:

```
 var maskHeight = $(document).height();
        var maskWidth = $(window).width();


        //Set height and width to mask to fill up the whole screen  
        $('#mask').css({ 'width': maskWidth, 'height': maskHeight });
```

It is ok bue the mask is contained in a div in the page.. So the mask set his position from the top left of.. the div!
How can I set the position to the top left of the whole page? thanks a lot for any ideas..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the mask CSS to:

```
#mask
{
    position: fixed; 
    top:0; left:0; 
    width:100%; height:100%;
    background: red;
}
```

It is going to start at the point 0 and cover the whole page, regardless of the scroll due the `position: fixed`

[Example on jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/3d3Jy/)

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="maskPage">
<div>
```

Css

```
.maskPage
{
 top:0; 
 left:0; 
 width:100%; 
 height:100%;
 background: #ccc;    
 position: fixed; 
}
```